# Want to know how to shift a UILabel

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm sorry if there is a stupidly simple answer to this question, but I've been looking around on the internet for a straight, simple answer, and haven't really gotten one. All I want to do is shift a UILabel from one spot to another on an iPad screen. I don't want it to be instantaneous, I want it to be animated, so how would I do this? Any help (with a lot of patience for stupid questions ^_^;) would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"myMoveAnimation" context:nil];  
aUIButton.center = CGMakePoint(newX, newY);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

For the lambda lovers...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:secondsToTake delay:0
        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
        animations:^{
          aUIButton.center = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
        }
        completion:^(BOOL finished){ /* Some code for to run when complete /* }];
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I guess I was confused about the UIView part. I didn't know that could just be applied to UILabel like that.

Comment: just for future reference... the animation with blocks is the only type of animation which is going to be allowed from ios 4...

Comment: @learner2010 : Not quite. "Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later", but it's not a question of "allowed" - they're just warning us that it'll be deprecated (probably in iOS 5).